# Flutter | Minutes and seconds on slider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently coding a flutter app, a timer, and a slider is needed to choose the timer's value.

```
          children: [
            CupertinoSlider(
                value: _pomodoroValue,
                min: 0.30,
                max: 60,
                divisions: 200,
                onChanged: (selectedValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _pomodoroValue = selectedValue;
                  });
                }),
            Text('${_pomodoroValue.toString()}')
          ],
        ),
```

My idea is to have a minimum of 30 seconds to a maximum of 60 minutes, but with the above code, the slider returns just decimals.

How can I have like at the beginning 0:30, then 1:00, 1:30, 2:00 etc...?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use seconds to keep things simple.

```
Column(
  children: [
    CupertinoSlider(
      value: _pomodoroValue,
      min: 30,
      max: 3600,
      divisions: (3600 / 30 - 1).toInt(),
      onChanged: (selectedValue) {
        setState(() {
          _pomodoroValue = selectedValue;
        });
      },
    ),
    Text(Duration(seconds: _pomodoroValue.toInt()).toHHmmss())
  ]
),
```

`toHHmmss` method as extension. Copied from [toString](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration/toString.html).

```
extension on Duration {
  String toHHmmss() {
    var microseconds = inMicroseconds;

    var hours = microseconds ~/ Duration.microsecondsPerHour;
    microseconds = microseconds.remainder(Duration.microsecondsPerHour);

    if (microseconds < 0) microseconds = -microseconds;

    var minutes = microseconds ~/ Duration.microsecondsPerMinute;
    microseconds = microseconds.remainder(Duration.microsecondsPerMinute);

    var minutesPadding = minutes < 10 ? "0" : "";

    var seconds = microseconds ~/ Duration.microsecondsPerSecond;
    microseconds = microseconds.remainder(Duration.microsecondsPerSecond);

    var secondsPadding = seconds < 10 ? "0" : "";

    return "$hours:"
        "$minutesPadding$minutes:"
        "$secondsPadding$seconds";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove all the 0s after the seconds? I get like 0:35:00.000000

Comment: Added format to HH:mm:ss.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the times just is a number, you don't want `decimals`? use `int` instead. `seconds` divider to `60` to get `minutes`.

```dart
void main() {
  getTime(times) {
    final minutes = times ~/ 60;
    final seconds = times % 60;
    formatZero(num) => '$num'.length == 2 ? num : '0$num';
    return "${formatZero(minutes)}:${formatZero(seconds)}";
  }

  print(getTime(30));
  print(getTime(60));
  print(getTime(90));
  print(getTime(99));
}
```

Result

```
00:30
01:00
01:30
01:39
```

Comment: So how do I implement this into my current code?

Comment: @FilippoGenoni `min:30`,`max:3600` and `divisions:30` then use `Text(getTime(_pomodoroValue))` bro.

Comment: @Tuan what is ~/ and % syntax mean

Comment: instead of string, can return to datetime? like `Datetime.from()`

Comment: @FilippoGenoni it called `operator`, see more [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators).

Comment: @FilippoGenoni your case is not `Datetime` actually

Comment: @FilippoGenoni look like you are very very new in dart and flutter here. please read [this](https://dart.dev/) and [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/) to improve.